# Problema com ponteiros - remover elemento numa árvore binária de busca

Tags: c, ponteiro, árvore-binária

Está tendo algum problema na passagem do ponteiro raiz por parâmetro para a função ***remove_node***.

Essa função é iterativa, tem apenas uma chamada recursiva no último caso. Sendo assim, é preciso usar dois ponteiros. Conforme vamos caminhando na árvore binária de busca até encontrar o elemento a ser removido, vamos mantendo os endereços do memória do nó atual (*current*) e do anterior(*previous*). Mas está dando erro na atribuição do endereço de memória do raiz para o ponteiro *current*.

Obrigado!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
 int data;
 struct Node* left;
 struct Node* right;    
}Node;    


Node* get_new_node(int data)
{
 Node* new_node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
 new_node->data = data;
 new_node->left = new_node->right = NULL;
 return new_node;
}    


Node* insert(Node *root, int data)
{
 if(root == NULL){
     root = get_new_node(data);
 }else if(data <= root->data){
     root->left = insert(root->left, data);
 }else if(data > root->data){
     root->right = insert(root->right, data);
 }
 return root;
}

int get_min_value(Node *root)
{
 while(root->left != NULL)
    root = root->left;
 return root->data;
}

void remove_node(Node *root, int value)
{
 int is_remove_node_a_left_child;
 int value_min_tmp;
 Node* previous, current;
 Node* root_min_tmp;

 previous = NULL;
 current = root;

//finding the node to be removed
 while(value != current->data)
 {
    previous = current;
    if(value < current->data)
    {
        current = current->left;
        is_remove_node_a_left_child = 1;
    }else
    {
        current = current->right;
        is_remove_node_a_left_child = 0;
    }
 }
//current is now pointing to the node to be removed, and previous, to its parent

//cases:
 if((current->left == NULL) && (current->right == NULL))
 {//the remove node has no child
    if(is_remove_node_a_left_child == 1)
        previous->left = NULL;
    else
        previous->right = NULL;
    free(current);
 }else if((current->left == NULL) && (current->right != NULL))
 {//the remove node has only a right child
    if(is_remove_node_a_left_child == 1)
        previous->left = current->right;
    else
        previous->right = current->right;
    free(current);
 }else if((current->left != NULL) && (current->right == NULL))
 {//the remove node has only a left child
    if(is_remove_node_a_left_child == 1)
        previous->left = current->left;
    else
        previous->right = current->left;
    free(current);
 }else
 {//the remove node has a left and a right child
    value_min_tmp = get_min_value(current->right);
    remove_node(current->right, value_min_tmp);
    current->data = value_min_tmp;
 }

}


void show_bst_in_order(Node* root)
{
 if(root == NULL)
    return;
 show_bst_in_order(root->left);
 printf("%d ", root->data);
 show_bst_in_order(root->right);
}


int main(){
 int return_value;
 Node *root = NULL;

 root = insert(root, 10);
 root = insert(root, 3);
 root = insert(root, 1);
 root = insert(root, 7);
 root = insert(root, 19);
 root = insert(root, 25);
 root = insert(root, 30);
 root = insert(root, 6);
 root = insert(root, 4);

 printf("Binary search tree in order:\n");
 show_bst_in_order(root);
 printf("\n");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você declarou apenas a variável previous como ponteiro. A variável current é do tipo struct Node. Para declarar as duas variaveis como ponteiros faça como segue abaixo.

```
void remove_node(Node* root, int value){
    ....

    Node* previous, *current; // <---------- Modifique aqui
    Node* root_min_tmp;
    previous = NULL;
    current =root;
    .....
}
```